# Use the function "connect to server" in Nautilus

Tags: server

I saw on the net that I could connect to a remote server using Nautilus.
I have never done that before.

I have a little homework webpage to keep my students occupied.

I have just rented a cloud server with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I want to leave my shared web-hosting.

I can access the new cloud server using ssh. I have set up MySQL, PHP, phpMyAdmin

I connected to my localhost using in the "connect to server" box of "other locations" sftp://127.0.0.1 no problem

What I want to do is copy various folders from my laptop /var/www/html/ to the cloud server. Say my cloud ip is: 123.456.789.123

Could I do that from my laptop using:

sftp://123.456.789.123

in the "connect to server" box at the bottom of "other locations"?

Then, just copy and paste folders from the laptop to the cloud??

That would make life easy!

I set up sftp on my laptop.
Do I need to set up sftp on the cloud server too?

Is there a better way to get my folders and files from this laptop to the cloud server??

Comment: Could I do that from my laptop using:

sftp://123.456.789.123  Have you tried?

Comment: No yet, I'm always worried I might cause a meltdown!

Comment: What meltdown? There is no possible way that can hurt anything. It will either work or it will not.

Comment: Just tried, "connection refused"

Comment: Contact hosting company and find out if they allow what you are trying to do.

Comment: Tried Filezilla. First wouldn't connect, I was using the wrong protocol. When I changed to sftp protocol, WORKED!